# Creating an instance of a menu item

Tags: android, menu, menuitem

I want to create an instance of a menu item in the options menu and then manipulate it.

Here is the code for the item in the menu xml:

```
<item
    android:id="@+id/colour"
    android:orderInCategory="1"
    android:showAsAction="never"
    android:title="Colour"
    android:checkable="true"
    android:checked="true" />
```

Here is the **attempted** code in my Activity class:

```
MenuItem i = (MenuItem)findViewById(R.id.colour);
i.setChecked(false);
```

The code above has no syntax errors, but the app breaks when it runs. I've googled for a little while and can't find an answer.

**EDIT**

I've put this at the top of my `activity class`:

```
private Menu menus; // create global Menu variable 'menus' that is the instance of the menu that holds the menu item I want to create and manipulate
private MenuItem item; // create global MenuItem variable 'item' that is the instance of the menu item I want to create and manipulate
```

And I've put this in my `onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu)` method:

```
getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
menus = menu; // assign global 'menus' Menu variable to be the parameter 'menu' Menu variable for this method
// or this.menus = menu; // both give the same result
```

And I've put this code in a `button listener` in my `activity class`:

```
item = menus.findItem(R.id.settings); // assign the instance of the MenuItem to be an item in the instance of the Menu variable created

if (item.isChecked())
{
    item.setChecked(false);
}
else if (!item.isChecked())
{
    item.setChecked(true);
}
```

Even when I comment out the if structure above, I still get this logCat error:

```
09-02 07:05:34.900: E/AndroidRuntime(9036): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
09-02 07:05:34.900: E/AndroidRuntime(9036): java.lang.NullPointerException
09-02 07:05:34.900: E/AndroidRuntime(9036):     at com.mikeyaworski.secretnotepad.Main$6.onClick(Main.java:615)
09-02 07:05:34.900: E/AndroidRuntime(9036):     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4203)
09-02 07:05:34.900: E/AndroidRuntime(9036):     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:17189)
09-02 07:05:34.900: E/AndroidRuntime(9036):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:615)
09-02 07:05:34.900: E/AndroidRuntime(9036):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
09-02 07:05:34.900: E/AndroidRuntime(9036):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
09-02 07:05:34.900: E/AndroidRuntime(9036):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4961)
09-02 07:05:34.900: E/AndroidRuntime(9036):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
09-02 07:05:34.900: E/AndroidRuntime(9036):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
09-02 07:05:34.900: E/AndroidRuntime(9036):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1004)
09-02 07:05:34.900: E/AndroidRuntime(9036):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:771)
09-02 07:05:34.900: E/AndroidRuntime(9036):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

When I comment out the line: `item = menus.findItem(R.id.settings);`, I get no error. So the problem is in that line of code. Every line of code I've added has no syntax errors.

Can anyone tell me what's wrong with this method of creating and manipulating the `instance` of the `MenuItem` in any `method` of my `activity class`?

Comment: What is trying to do? setChecked with menu?

Comment: Can you post the logcat with the error?

Comment: Check >>> when <<< the the setChecked method is running

Comment: Two things: 1. Are you sure that the resource you pointing is available ? 2. If its not the typo(ref. to your edit) then the way you are assinging the value at onCreateOptionsMenu is wrong..... it should be like this.menu = menus not menu = menus.... try this you won't get any errors

Comment: @Mohit I should have added this in as well: I originally tried `this.menus = menu`, but then changed it so `menus = menu` and it made no difference (error both times). I'm not sure why `this` is in your code anyways. Also, you're saying that `menus`, the `global variable`, should be on the right side of the equal sign. That's your typo right? It should be on the left if I'm assigning the `global scope` `menus` to be the  `parameter` `menu`. Also, I'm not sure how to tell if the resource is available. It is a `MenuItem`, if that's what you mean.

Comment: are u still getting error?

Comment: can you share full acitivty code using pastie.org?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/36663/discussion-between-mohit-and-mike-yaworski)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to do it this way in your Activity class:

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

    super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
    MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.main, menu); // inflate your menu resource

    if (menu != null) {
        MenuItem color = menu.findItem(R.id.color);
        if (color != null) {
            color.setChecked(false);
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

Comment: Works for what I'm doing. I'd still like to know how to create an instance of the item in any other method, besides `OnCreateOptionsMenu` though.

Comment: There is no way to do it. You need to save an instance of the Menu when it is created and then use that.

Comment: @mikeyaworski You can get an instance of `MenuItem` in every method where you have your `Menu` instance such as `onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu)`, `onPrepareOptionsMenu(Menu menu)`, `onOptionsMenuClosed(Menu menu)`, `onMenuOpened(int featureId, Menu menu)` and `onOptionsItemSeleted(Menu menu)`.

Answer (score 0):

*Answer to you second query*

Here is how you can manipulate the menu instance very easily within those methods as well where you don't have Menu instance as a passed parameter:

create a global **Menu** variable:

```
private Menu menu;
```

Now in **onCreateOptionMenu()** assign current menu instance to the one you declared globally like this:

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) 
{
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu, menu);

    this.menu = menu;

    return true;
}
```

Now you can use it anywhere in the activity you want.

e.g (i am going to update some menu icons)

```
private MenuItem item1, item2;
Boolean original = true;

private void update() {

    item1 = menu.findItem(R.id.todaySched);
    item2 = menu.findItem(R.id.infoLog);

    if (original) {
        item1.setIcon(getResources().getDrawable(
                      android.R.drawable.ic_menu_search));
        item2.setIcon(getResources().getDrawable(
                      android.R.drawable.ic_menu_report_image));
        original = false;
    } else if (!original) {

        item1.setIcon(getResources().getDrawable(
                      android.R.drawable.ic_menu_my_calendar));
        item2.setIcon(getResources().getDrawable(
                      android.R.drawable.ic_menu_info_details));
        original = true;
    }
}
```

Comment: actually you have the `Menu` instance :)

Comment: You can get an instance of MenuItem in every method where you have your Menu instance such as onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu), onPrepareOptionsMenu(Menu menu), onOptionsMenuClosed(Menu menu), onMenuOpened(int featureId, Menu menu) and onOptionsItemSeleted(Menu menu).......    But if you look at ur comment carefully you just suggested him that he can only have the menu instance with in these. which is not true.

Comment: and also look at his comment....he want to manipulate the menu instance where ever he wants in the activity. Which of course not possible with what you have suggested. Is it?

Comment: Sorry for not getting back to you for a few days. Anyways, this method is good and I totally understand it, but it doesn't work for some reason. The app just breaks. I'll accept your answer and give you an upvote if I get your method working.

Comment: @Mohit check my edited answer to see how I implemented your answer to my code, but still got an error. I'd like to get your way of doing it working.

Comment: @mikeyaworski Pls have a look at this demo code(checked and is working fine) http://pastie.org/8298787

Comment: @Mohit thanks for working something out, but that is incredibly complicated for me to implement into my own class. The button listener stuff is really different and can't find my button id. I also have no idea what alpha and beta is, so I can't fix those errors either. It's too complicated for me to be worth doing, but I appreciate the time you've spent.

Comment: @mikeyaworski This is just a demo code. You can create a menu item on your button click by just calling " mymenu.add(0, 10, 0, "Info")
     .setIcon(android.R.drawable.ic_menu_info_details)
     .setShowAsAction(MenuItem.SHOW_AS_ACTION_IF_ROOM); " ...HERE mymenu is that global variable